# pdfimages wont extract all images

Tags: pdf, images, pdftk

I'm using pdfimages to extract images from a [PDF File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxm3reib7fmhuna/Tecnologo_Oftalmica.pdf?dl=0).
I've counted at last 10 images.
But the program will only extract 4.

```
pdfimages -all file.pdf i
```

Generates

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 victor victor   61389 Jul 14 21:48 i-000.png
-rw-rw-r--    1 victor victor      88 Jul 14 21:48 i-001.png
-rw-rw-r--    1 victor victor    5226 Jul 14 21:48 i-002.png
-rw-rw-r--    1 victor victor   95657 Jul 14 21:48 i-003.png
```

Am I missing some setting?

How can I extract all images?

Comment: My version of pdfimages allows this parameter... "  -all           : equivalent to -png -tiff -j -jp2 -jbig2 -ccitt"

Comment: How do you know that the PDF has more than 4 images?  `pdfimages` only retrieve raster images, vector based images (e.g. eps) are not touched by `pdfimages`.

Answer (score 5):

Pdfimages only supports raster images. What you are seeing in your PDF is most likely a vector graphic.

I don't think there is a way to extract them automatically but you can use tools like *Inkscape* or *LibreOffice Draw* to get such a graphic manually. The process is the same for both:

1. Open the PDF
2. Select the area of the graphic
3. Copy to clipboard (Ctrl + C)
4. Get a new document (Ctrl + N)
5. Paste (Ctrl + V)
6. Move to top left and adjust page size (Inkscape can automate both: Ctrl+Shift+R)
7. Draw: Export / Inkscape: Save as (Ctrl+Shift+S)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the rep to upvote, but my answer is same as answered above for Inkscape, except recommend to use the File->Export PNG Image... option to specify the image resolution. For my case of an eps graphic of a paper map (3'by3' in hardcopy), I imported to Inkscape at quality factor of 30, and output at 5000x5000 to get a good result. Whereas I think Ctrl-Shift-S by default is fairly low resolution. My particular case also crashed out LibreOffice pretty harshly, which was unexpected. The current LibreOffice is otherwise very good software in my experience.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426430)

Answer (score 0):

I also have a suggestion: there is this online tool from Semadox: https://www.semadox.com/pdf-image-extraction . There you can extract the images in original resolution.

Disclaimer: I am the founder of Semadox, but the tool is for free and will always stay free.